# log4j configuration for struts2

Tags: java, struts2, log4j

I would like to configure my log4j file for a production environment with struts2. I have the below configuration...

```
log4j.logger.com.opensymphony.xwork2=ERROR
log4j.logger.ognl=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.struts2=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.struts2.util.StrutsTypeConverter=ERROR
log4j.logger.freemarker=ERROR

#apache torque which is my ORM needs to be add debug.. so I can see SQLs being
#printed
log4j.logger.org.apache.torque=DEBUG

#this is my source package base which need be at debug
log4j.logger.com.aesthete=DEBUG
```

The above configuration is fine, except that any errors in struts2 is not being printed out to the log at all. Would be grateful for some help in the correct configuration that most users in a production environment running struts2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ERROR` is *really* restrictive; I couldn't recommend that for production. `WARN` is the absolute least I'd have in production--you could miss a lot of very important information, particularly at startup.

IMO, `INFO` is more-typical, and most useful.

`DEBUG` should rarely be used in a production environment; if you're relying on it I'd suggest that your logging was put in the code at the wrong level. `DEBUG` is for just that--debugging.

I've never restricted S2 to anything greater than `WARN`, but I tend to leave things at `INFO` level unless specifically trying to debug an issue. On production I also use a fast layout, again unless there's a particularly component that's being worked on.

Comment: Thanks Dave.. Your answers really help a lot. Now that I notice, your name is all over google on all articles regarding struts2.. Did a search.. and only now realise that I am talking to an author of a book on struts2.. :) Well thank you.. and thanks stack overflow !

Comment: @sethu: he is the core committer of struts2 in Apache :)

Comment: @sethu umesh: I am but one of many--I just have a big mouth ;)